# Assign an IP to a MAC Address to DHCP POOL

Tags: cisco, ip, ipv4, dhcp, mac

The idea is that I want to have a static IP for the MAC computer always assign me the IP . please help , as would the commands ?

I have a cisco 3650 switch core where I configured the DHCP and VLAN former systems administrator assigned an IP to MAC address as follows :

- ip dhcp pool NAME
- host 192.168.17.137 255.255.255.0
- client-identifier 0100.71cc.02XX.XX
- client-name NAME

---

but I do not know how to do it for a VLAN IP 17 as mentioned always assign me a static IP .

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

On a Cisco IOS DHCP server, it is pretty simple. In the DHCP pool configuration, use the `address` command to assign an IP address to a MAC address:

```
address <ip-address> hardware-address <mac-address>
```

[Preassigning IP Addresses and Associating Them to a Client](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/15-sy/dhcp-15-sy-book/dhcp-prt-bsd-aa.html#GUID-D3427E9D-D0F3-4FFE-889C-8091A84006C6):

> ### Preassigning IP Addresses and Associating Them to a Client
>
> Perform this task to preassign an IP address and associate it to a
>   client identified by a client ID or MAC address.
>
> For port-based address assignment, you must perform the task in the
>   [Automatically Generating a Subscriber Identifier for a DHCP Message
>   Received on a Port](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/15-sy/dhcp-15-sy-book/dhcp-prt-bsd-aa.html#GUID-0709D49E-5CD2-46A0-BEE5-D24BFAA003BE) task to associate the client ID with the
>   subscriber ID. The subscriber ID value is based on the short name of
>   the port to which the directly connected device is attached.
>
> Configure a normal DHCP pool by supplying any DHCP options and lease
>   time. Preassigned addresses are automatically excluded from normal
>   dynamic IP address assignment. Preassigned addresses cannot be used in
>   host pools, but there can be multiple preassigned addresses per DHCP
>   address pool.
>
> **Note**
>
> Only one IP address can be assigned per port.
>
> Preassigned addresses (also called reserved addresses) cannot be
>   cleared by using the **clear ip dhcp binding** command.
>
> **SUMMARY STEPS**
>
> 1. enable
> 2. configure terminal
> 3. ip dhcp pool *name*
> 4. network *network-number* [*mask* | / *prefix-length*]
> 5. address *ip-address* client-id *string* [ascii]
> 6. address *ip-address* hardware-address *mac-address* [*hardware-number*]
> 7. end
> 8. show ip dhcp pool [*name*]
> 9. show ip dhcp binding

**Edit:**

Based on your comments:

```
ip dhcp pool Test-Pool
network 192.168.17.0/24
address 192.168.17.137 hardware-address 0100.71cc.02XX
```

Comment: For example I have to do the following :

1.conf t
2. ip dhcp pool DCANTOS
3. host 192.168.17.137 255.255.255.0
4.client -identifier 0100.71cc.02XX.XX
5. client -name DCANTOS

There not know what else follows?

Comment: There is no `host` keyword. Use the `address` keyword. You really only need `address <ip-address> hardware-address <mac-address>` in the DHCP pool after you have defined the `network` address.

Comment: Previously the old admin CORE performed it something like this:


ip dhcp pool (hostname)
   host (ip address) (netmask)
   hardware-address (mac)


The example he gives me , not if it's what I want

Comment: There is NO `host` keyword; erase that from your brain. In the summary steps above, you do steps 1 to 4 to create a DHCP pool for the network. You can skip step 5 and just do step 6 (forget about the `[hardware-number]`) to reserve the IP address in the pool for the host: `address 192.168.17.137  hardware-address 0100.71cc.02XX`

Comment: @dcantos, I edited my answer for your addresses in your comment. You must first create the DHCP pool as normal, and just add an `address` line to associate a specific address with the MAC address.

Comment: then the other I say no good ?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of device you got that from, but I'm pointing you to the Cisco IOS DHCP server like you would have on your router. If your DHCP server is a stand-alone server or some other model, it will be something else. I have a link to the Cisco documentation in my answer, and I edited the answer to give you what you need to do for a Cisco IOS DHCP server. Your question has the Cisco tag. If this is really a different device, then you should edit your answer to clarify that.

Comment: Nothing happens if I work with VLAN ?

Comment: Explain your network. Where are you putting the DHCP server (router, layer-3 switch, etc.), and where is the interface that defines the network which uses the DHCP pool (router, layer-3 switch, etc.)? If the router has an interface covered by the DHCP pool network, then it should automatically work. If the DHCP pool is on a device other than where the network it serves is defined, you need to use a helper address for the interface where the network is defined.

Comment: I have a switch core cisco configured the dhcp in which the core replicates settings to switch other cisco have like 20 VLAN and each VLAN has its dhcp what I want and had before was a configuration that will assign the IP to a mac if you I do a show run I can see dhcp pool created as follows:

ip dhcp pool host
 host 192.168.xx.xx 255.255.255.0
 client-identifier mac-address
 client-name host

so my question

Comment: You should edit your question to include all the relevant information. How are the network devices connected, where are the different networks assigned gateway addresses (interface, SVI, etc.), and what are the configurations? Let's quit playing 20 questions, and have you edit your question to include all your information.

Comment: to see all processes I have it set to the Core Switch , DHCP and VLANs all, the former administrator of CISCO not as assigning IP addresses to MAC because seeing a show run I see assignments as :

ip dhcp pool OGAMARRA
 host 192.168.17.138 255.255.255.0
 client-identifier 0100.71cc.020X.XX
 client-name OGAMARRA


my question is to do what you tell me I would not affect anything in the VLAN # 17 which is the same network 192.168.17.0 because that I have created VLAN 1 to 20

Comment: You cannot properly format in a comment. Edit your question to include what I have asked you for. Be sure to include the device models and configuration, and how the devices are connected. Your question needs to include everything if your want to get a correct answer. We can only answer what you ask.