# cisco catalyst 6500 not honoring static ip assignments

Tags: dhcp, mac-address, cisco-catalyst

I have a catalyst 6500 sup720 running 15.1(2)sy6 and i have attempted to have a set of mac addresses to get a specific ip from dhcp. below is what shows on the bindings.

```
10.1.4.200       01e0.508b.xxxx.a5       Infinite                Manual
10.1.4.201       01ec.71db.xxxx.ad       Infinite                Manual
10.1.4.206       01e0.508b.xxxx.a5       Jan 23 2024 11:47 AM    Automatic
```

below is the dhcp pool information.

```
ip dhcp pool 10.1.4.192Cam
network 10.1.4.192 255.255.255.192
domain-name xxx
dns-server x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
default-router 10.1.4.193 
 address 10.1.4.200 hardware-address 01e0.508b.xxxx.a5
 address 10.1.4.201 hardware-address 01ec.71db.xxxx.ad
 address 10.1.4.202 hardware-address 01f0.0000.xxxx.24
 address 10.1.4.203 hardware-address 01f0.0000.xxxx.fa
 address 10.1.4.204 hardware-address 016c.1c71.xxxx.63
 address 10.1.4.205 hardware-address 01c0.56e3.xxxx.8f
 address 10.1.4.209 hardware-address 01e0.508b.xxxx.a5
```

*Below is the answer that worked from the information that Ron Maupin♦ provided. the 6500 has slightly differen syntax.*

```
ip dhcp pool 10.1.4.192Cam
network 10.1.4.192 255.255.255.192
domain-name xxx
dns-server x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
default-router 10.1.4.193 
 address 10.1.4.200 client-id 01e0.508b.xxxx.a5
 address 10.1.4.201 client-id 01ec.71db.xxxx.ad
```

**Note:** I had 2 tasmota esp8265 devices and a old kindle that required Hardware-address in order to reliably get a static ip.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32600/assign-an-ip-to-a-mac-address-to-dhcp-pool ironically states the opposet and is for the 15.1 ios release how ever it did not work for me.

Comment: Updated as not all devices honor client-id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device uses BOOTP, then you use the `hardware-address`. Since you seem to be doing DHCP, you must use the `client-identifier`.

Note from [Cisco Documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/xe-3se/3850/dhcp-xe-3se-3850-book/config-dhcp-server.html):

> Step 6    hardware-address hardware-address [protocol-type |
> hardware-number]
>
> Example: Device(dhcp-config)# hardware-address b708.1388.f166 ethernet
> Specifies a hardware address for the client.
>
> ***This command is used for BOOTP requests.*** Note        The hardware address specified here is considered for a DHCP client that does not
> send a client identifier in the packet.

-and-

> Step 5    client-identifier unique-identifier
>
> Example: Device(dhcp-config)# client-identifier 01b7.0813.8811.66
> Specifies the unique identifier for DHCP clients.
>
> ***This command is used for DHCP requests. DHCP clients require client identifiers.*** You can specify the unique identifier for the client
> in either of the following ways: A 7-byte dotted hexadecimal notation.
> For example, 01b7.0813.8811.66, where 01 represents the Ethernet media
> type and the remaining bytes represent the MAC address of the DHCP
> client. A 27-byte dotted hexadecimal notation. For example,
> 7665.6e64.6f72.2d30.3032.342e.3937.6230.2e33.3734.312d.4661.302f.31. The equivalent ASCII string for this hexadecimal value is
> vendor-0024.97b0.3741-fa0/1, where vendor represents the vendor,
> 0024.97b0.3741 represents the MAC address of the source interface, and fa0/1 represents the source interface of the DHCP client. See the
> Troubleshooting section for information about how to determine the
> client identifier of the DHCP client. Note     The identifier
> specified here is considered for a DHCP client that sends a client
> identifier in the packet.

Comment: Thankyou for providing a complete answer like this. Iwill have IOT devices soon that need BOOTP as well I have edited my question to include the answer provided at the bottom as the syntax was different for my device.