# Cisco catalyst 6500 not assigning static dhcp assignments to a couple of devices

Tags: cisco, dhcp, static

in the following question [cisco catalyst 6500 not honoring static ip assignments](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84919/cisco-catalyst-6500-not-honoring-static-ip-assignments) I had been able to get 16 out of the 20 devices im working with to honor the static ip settings.  4 devices are for some reason not getting a static.  During logging I kept testing one device and in the dhcp logging it stated assigned .... to 10.1.4.34 even though it was assigned 10.1.4.24

```
10.1.4.24        0134.987a.xxxx.1d       Infinite                Manual
10.1.4.37        3498.7axx.xx1d          Feb 06 2024 05:19 AM    Automatic
```

the phone had the 01 in front of the mac and perfectly matched the Infinite entry for that device.

the 2 iot devices including 10.1.4.24 did not nor did a kindle I believe.

These devices are connecting to a wifi acces point and the AP is poe in to the cisco. it supports vlas and trunking how ever is using the native vlan for the specific dhcp range.
there are a few devices that are actually wired directly to the switch and probably 10+ being wifi. below is the method of addign to the pool

```
address 10.1.4.24 client-id 0134.987a.xxxx.1d
```

Comment: Read the answer to that question again. 01+MAC *IS NOT* a "hardware-address" -- it's a client-id.

Comment: Sorry you are correct I grabbed the line from the wrong section in the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices need Hardware-address to reliably get a static ip.   I had on old kindle and two esp8265 devices that accepted static ip's from hardware-address while ignored Client-id assignments.